# iOS Dev Center Error: Enter a valid phone number for the selected country

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have 2FA turned on in the iOS Dev Center with phone numbers, and recently when trying to access it, at the selecting phone number stage the error "Enter a valid phone number for the selected country" keeps popping up when I select an existing phone number to send verification code to. This process has always worked for years but now I'm stuck, has anyone else experienced this or know of a workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by passing 2FA with the other phone number, remove the supposedly invalid phone number from the Apple ID Security section, and then re-add it... It's the exact same phone number, but for some reason removing it and re-adding it did the trick.